# Get thumbnail from Office file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, ms-office, thumbnails

I want to retrieve the thumbnail image from any office-file (Word, Excel, etc.) using `GetThumbnailAsync` method.

```
StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem)
```

[StorageFolder.GetThumbnailAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227212.aspx)

[Guidelines for thumbnails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465350.aspx)

In the case `Thumbs.db` exists, `GetThumbnailAsync` returns the document thumbnail. However, In the case of there is no `Thumbs.db` it return an icon.

Can I retrieve the thumbnail image from any Office file, when there is no `Thumbs.db`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `DocumentsView` `ThumbnailMode`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. On DocumentView mode, GetThumbnailAsync returns an icon.

Comment: So the other mode generates a thumbnail of the actual content of the file?

Comment: In the case of there is no Thumbs.db, All mode generate an icon for office-files.